# How can I switch to a new branch and restore changes?

Tags: git, github

While working on branch `feature_1` with a lot of code changes and new files, I expected that if I `git checkout -b feature_2` I would be presented with a working space that is based on the `master` branch, meaning all the changes from `feature_1` are saved in that branch and not visible while working under `feature_2`.

Does git have that feature? If not, what's the workflow that supports that in git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The described result you expected is *not* what you asked git for.

Uncommitted changes stay in the working tree until committed (or reset), regardless of the checked out branch.

---

**Storing your `feature_1` changes**
If you want to keep the ongoing (and I assume, unfinished) changes on your branch, commit then temporarily (`git commit -am "TEMP - DO NOT MERGE ME"`). When you'll come back to this branch, you'll be able to undo this temporary commit easily (`git reset HEAD^`) to resume work.

*(Alternatively, you could also have stashed your uncommitted changes, see the doc for git stash [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash))*

---

**Creating the new branch**
To checkout your new branch with `master` as its base, you have to be explicit (pass it as second parameter), so `git checkout -b feature_2 master`

Comment: @eftshift0 Well, I admit I've been overjoyed :'-) Thank you...

Comment: Are the 2 things you mentioned (storing and creating) 2 steps that I have to take? Wouldn't storing (committing) the changes make them stick to the history and visible for everybody? Would `git reset HEAD^` delete that temporary commit from the history?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to provide master as an additional parameter to checkout. `git checkout -b feature_2 master`. The trick is that no branch has any special meaning/importance/precedence to git. So if you don't provide that additional parameter, git will use your current branch as the starting point for the new branch.

Comment: Even when I do that, my `git status` still shows changes from the previous branch. Do I have to commit the changes in the the previous branch before doing that?

Comment: But wait... you didn't commit stuff into `feature_1`? That won't fly. As long as changes are not committed, those uncommitted changes will be going anywhere you move.

Comment: if the changes are not ready to be committed, then you should `git stash` them so that your working tree gets cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

to change the branch, type `git checkout branch_name`  command.then use `git merge branch_name_2`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to develop the habit of switching to master/main (or whatever your "trunk branch" is) before you create a new branch. You also need to develop the habit of making sure this branch is up to date before you create a new branch - so changes are not being made to a stale version. This is particularly important if you are working within a team or other repos with multiple contributors. Because of the distributed nature of git, this does not come for free.

I would suggest something like the following sequence:

1. Check your existing branch does not have outstanding stuff to commit, if so commit, throw away or whatever
2. git checkout master
3. git pull
4. git checkout -b feature_2